# Function that return the number of bytes necessary to store a long value

Tags: java

I have created a function that returns the number of bytes necessary to store a long value. The value must be in `[Long.MIN_VALUE, Long.MAX_VALUE].`

```
private static final int ONE_BYTE_MAX = (1 << 7) - 1; // 127
```

the ONE_BYTE_MAX value will be 127

```
private static final int ONE_BYTE_MIN = -(1 << 7);  // -128
```

the ONE_BYTE_MIN value will be -128

```
private static final int TWO_BYTE_MAX = (1 << 15) - 1; 

private static final int TWO_BYTE_MIN = -(1 << 15);

private static final int THREE_BYTE_MAX = (1 << 23) - 1; 

private static final int THREE_BYTE_MIN = -(1 << 23);

private static final long FOUR_BYTE_MAX = (1L << 31) - 1;

private static final long FOUR_BYTE_MIN = -(1L << 31);

private static final long FIVE_BYTE_MAX = (1L << 39) - 1; 

private static final long FIVE_BYTE_MIN = -(1L << 39);

private static final long SIX_BYTE_MAX = (1L << 47) - 1; 

private static final long SIX_BYTE_MIN = -(1L << 47);

private static final long SEVEN_BYTE_MAX = (1L << 55) - 1; 

private static final long SEVEN_BYTE_MIN = -(1L << 55);
```

The Method

```
public static int getBytesForLongValue(long value) {
        if (value >= ONE_BYTE_MIN && value <= ONE_BYTE_MAX) {
            return 1;
        } else if (value >= TWO_BYTE_MIN && value <= TWO_BYTE_MAX) {
            return 2;
        } else if (value >= THREE_BYTE_MIN && value <= THREE_BYTE_MAX) {
            return 3;
        } else if (value >= FOUR_BYTE_MIN && value <= FOUR_BYTE_MAX) {
            return 4;
        }else if (value >= FIVE_BYTE_MIN && value <= FIVE_BYTE_MAX) {
            return 5;
        }else if (value >= SIX_BYTE_MIN && value <= SIX_BYTE_MAX) {
            return 6;
        }else if (value >= SEVEN_BYTE_MIN && value <= SEVEN_BYTE_MAX) {
            return 7;
        } else {
            return 8;
        }
    }
```

Is there an easy way to do in java

Comment: You could create an enum with two fields: min and max. Then iterate over that enum values and have only one if-statement inside the loop.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak Can you please explain in detail

Comment: And by the way, what you are really doing is not exactly correct. All negative numbers will start with 1 in their binary representation. Have a look at Two's Complement.

Comment: How about simply doing `value.SIZE`? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#SIZE

Comment: @umopapisdn 1. `value` is a primitive so that won't work. 2. `Long.SIZE` is a constant equal to 64.

Answer (score 3):

Although I think that we should leave the number of bytes to eight for long primitive type in Java, there is an alternative way to calculate the minimum numbers of byte to hold long value (including the sign bit). Also this approach could be used for calculate that size for ANY integer adjusting the signature of the method:

```
public static int getMinNoOfBytes(BigInteger value)
```

Nevertheless, here is the code:

```
public class Answer {

    public static int getMinNoOfBytes(long value) {
        BigInteger any = BigInteger.valueOf(value);
        return any.toByteArray().length;
    }


    //Test
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Long.MAX_VALYE
        System.out.println(getMinNoOfBytes(Long.MAX_VALUE));

        //Long.MIN_VALUE
        System.out.println(getMinNoOfBytes(Long.MIN_VALUE));

        //Any value
        System.out.println(getMinNoOfBytes(65536));

    }
}
```

The output is (as expected)

8
8
3

Comment: Very, very nice!

Comment: Nice one - no loops, no calculations, just a clever use of existing libraries :)

Comment: @zlakad Good one!

Answer (score 1):

You could create an enum with two fields: min and max. Then iterate over that enum values and have only one if-statement inside the loop:

```
public enum Range {

    ONE  (1, -(1L << 7 ), (1L << 7 ) - 1),
    TWO  (2, -(1L << 15), (1L << 15) - 1),
    THREE(3, -(1L << 23), (1L << 23) - 1),
    FOUR (4, -(1L << 31), (1L << 31) - 1),
    FIVE (5, -(1L << 39), (1L << 39) - 1),
    SIX  (6, -(1L << 47), (1L << 47) - 1),
    SEVEN(7, -(1L << 55), (1L << 55) - 1);

    public final int bytesNeeded;
    public final long min;
    public final long max;

    Range(int bytesNeeded, long min, long max) {
        this.bytesNeeded = bytesNeeded;
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public static int getNbBytesForLongValue(long value) {
        for (Range range : Range.values()) {
            if (range.min <= value && value <= range.max) {
                return range.bytesNeeded;
            }
        }
        return 8;
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

Looking at these enums definitions, it is actually quite easy to convert it into a loop altogether:

```
public static int getNbBytesForLongValue(long value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        if (-(1L << (7 + i * 8)) <= value && value <= (1L << (7 + i * 8)) - 1) {
            return i + 1;
        }
    }
    return 8;
}
```

Comment: way too long solution for a simple question, besides it consider `long` as a 64 bits value, tomorrow oracle can decide java 11 will have 128 bits long so this won't work anymore

Comment: @RafaelLima Java is not C. Oracle cannot decide to change size of a `long`. The [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1) is very specific on value range of the primitive types.

Comment: @Andreas, so you are telling me there wasn't any changes in java since its first release until nowadays? changing the size of a primitive type would be a bad idea since it wont be retrocompatible, but nothing avoids java to define a new primitive type with 256bits

Comment: @RafaelLima You're right. Nothing prevents Java from introducing *new* primitives of 128 or 256 bits, but the current primitives cannot be changed, since it would break backwards compatibility, so a `long` will always be 64 bit. The Java designers specifically wanted to avoid the primitive size chaos of the C language.

Comment: @RafaelLima Way too long solution? I count 8 lines, most of which don't have any significant code. I would think that you were referring to the first solution - which is mostly refactoring of OP's code - but you have added this comment over 30 minutes after my latest edit...

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the highest 1-bit, then you know how may bytes will be needed.

The method [`Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(long i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#numberOfLeadingZeros-long-) can be used for that.

Since a long has `Long.SIZE` bits (64 actually), it's easy to calculate, but you need special handling of zero and negative values.

```
public static int getNbBytesForLongValue1(long value) {
    if (value == 0)
        return 1;
    int bitLength;
    if (value > 0) {
        int leadingZeroes = Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(value);
        bitLength = Long.SIZE - leadingZeroes + 1/*positive sign bit*/;
    } else {
        int leadingOnes = Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(value ^ -1L);
        bitLength = Long.SIZE - leadingOnes + 1/*negative sign bit*/;
    }
    return (bitLength + 7) / 8; // round up to whole bytes
}
```

Which can be shortened to (if you want to be a bit obscure):

```
public static int getNbBytesForLongValue(long value) {
    return (value == 0 ? 1 : ((Long.SIZE - Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(value > 0 ? value : value ^ -1L)) >> 3) + 1);
}
```

Solution in one line of code, and without loops.

Comment: Not bad at all ;)

Answer (score 1):

In this answer we focus on the number of *bits* needed. From there on, the number of bytes can be calculated by ceil-dividing by 8.

```
int bytesNeeded(long number) {
    return (bitsNeeded(number) + 7) / 8;
}
```

I assume that we store all numbers in two's complement, therefore we need 5 instead of 4 bits to store the the number 8<sub>dec</sub> = **0**1000<sub>bin</sub> and so on.

## For numbers fitting into a `long`

```
int bitsNeeded(long number) {
    if (number < 0) {
        number = ~number; // same as -(number + 1)
    }
    return Long.SIZE - Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(number) + 1;
}
```

#### Results

```
 i | bitsNeeded(i) | binary representation of i in two's complement
---+---------------+-----------------------------------------------
-8 |      4        |  1000
-7 |      4        |  1001
-6 |      4        |  1010
-5 |      4        |  1011
-4 |      3        |   100
-3 |      3        |   101
-2 |      2        |    10
-1 |      1        |     1
 0 |      1        |     0
 1 |      2        |    01
 2 |      3        |   011
 3 |      3        |   011
 4 |      4        |  0100
 5 |      4        |  0101
 6 |      4        |  0110
 7 |      4        |  0111
 8 |      5        | 01000
```

## For bigger numbers

If you are interested in bigger numbers, you can store them in a `BigInteger`. Fortunately, `BigInteger` provides a very convenient method for what you want:

```
int bitsNeeded(BigInteger number) {
     return number.bitLength() + 1;
}
```

In case you don't care about big numbers but want to use `bitLength()` use

```
int bitsNeeded(long number) {
     return BigInteger.valueOf(number).bitLength() + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `Long` to `Binary String` and then get the `length` of the `String`.

```
public static int getNbBytesForLongValue(long value) {
    int length = Long.toBinaryString(value).length();
    int noOfByte = length%8 == 0 ? length/8 : (length/8 + 1);
    return noOfByte;
}
```

**Note:** Negative number's store as 2's compliment. So, `-10` will be stored as `1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110110`. So, you will get `8` as output (which is correct) instead of `2`.

Comment: I think there is some division by 8 missing. For `300` the result should be 2, not 9.

Comment: he wants bytes this will return bits

Comment: I think this would do: `int length = Long.toBinaryString(value).length(); return length / 8 + (length % 8 > 0 ? 1 : 0);`

Comment: By the way, I think it's worth adding a note that this actually returns different output than OP wanted. For example, for `-3` OP's solution would return `1`, while this solution will (correctly) return 8. That's because of how the negative numbers are represented: `-3` in two's complement is `1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111101`.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak is correct, not giving the desired output

Comment: @CorkKochi why you think it is not giving you correct output? As per Jaroslaw comment he wants to make a note that how negative number stored in binary.

Comment: @Downvoter can you please explian why the downvote? What exactly problem with my answer, so that I can make correction.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak Thanks for the suggestion. I have added it to my answer.

Comment: Instead of `length%8 == 0 ? length/8 : (length/8 + 1)` which requires two division operations, use `(length + 7) / 8`. It's a "round-up" operation

Comment: @Andreas yes this will optimize the solution. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak Question uses two's complement on however many bytes are used, so a 1-byte value is -128 to 127, a 2-byte value is -32768 to 32767, a 3-byte value is -8388608 to 8388607, and so forth, so *correct* solution for `-3` is 1, not 8.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `for` loop dividing the parameter by 128 and count the number of iteraction needed to reach 0.

```
public int countBytesNeeded(long l) {
    if (l == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    int result = 0;

    for (; l != 0; result++) {
        l = l / 128;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Using lower case L for variable name is not the best idea. It is too easy to mistake with digit one.

Comment: this is just a sample code... is not supposed to be copy pasted

Comment: @RafaelLima Even sample code should follow good naming conventions. It's about code readability, and sample code should be *more* readable, not less.